# method to find how often that number occurs in the array and copy each into the List

Tags: java, methods

I ws creating a method for my arrayList which is maxArray.

Been trying to figure this one out all night and can't seem to find to do it. Here is the code that I have got so far in doing this.

The problem that I am having is that it says `int cannot be converted to ArrayList<Integer>` At first I thought that what I was doing is right but half way through this thing gives me error.

MaxArray Method:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> maxArray(int[] array) {
           ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
           int max = arr.get(findMax(array));
            
           for (int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i++) {
               if (arr.get(i) > max) {
               max = arr.get(i);
       }
    
       return max;
   }
```

And My Main Method goes something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       ArrayAndArrayList arr1 = new ArrayAndArrayList();
       int[] array = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
       System.out.println(arr1.maxArray(array));
```

To give you more perspective about what I am doing. The instruction for this method was:

The instruction that was given to me was maxArray will be used as:
Keeps track of every occurrence of the max number in the given array.

- Returns an ArrayList that contains every occurrence of the max number.
- Uses the findMax(int[] array) method.
- If the array is empty, returns null.

[The task I am currently doing](https://pastebin.com/CGTq9zJp)

Comment: You are returning an int variable `max` but your function is expecting an `ArrayList<Integer>` to be returned.

Comment: I would expect this code to throw an exception trying to get an element from an empty array. Are you sure this is the code you’re running?

Comment: Yep, It throws an exception and I can't seem to understand how to get the value I needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to (1) find the maximum of an integer array and (2) return an array list that contains as many max elements as there are in the original array.

Something like this should work:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> maxArray(int[] array) {
    if (array.length == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    int max = findMax(array);
    for (int item : array) {
        if (item == max) {
            arr.add(item);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the method above you defined the return value to be ArrayList but in the loop you are using the get method, which returns a single element, and use it to set max. This variable max is what you return. If you want to return it as an ArrayList, you would need to declare one, add your element(s) to it and return this instead of max.